# No comma in leading zeros predefined way

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I don't want a comma for leading zeros. I can do it by padding required zeros, but I want the pattern which it gives by default.

`string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:000000000,0.00}",1234569)`

Actual: `"0,001,234,569.00"`

Expected: `"0001,234,569.00"`

Comment: Not possible without additional code. Very strange requirement. Why would you want that?

Comment: why would we need comma in leading zeros?

Comment: Thousands separators are there for better readability by humans. Leading zeroes actually decrease readability by humans. You usually only want leading zeroes for some text based formats that are to be read by machines. Additionally. the format you want will create different string lengths for different values while using leading zeroes is usually done to have the same string length for all values. So why combine thousands separators with leading zeroes?

Comment: @VMan why would someone need any leading zeros? Or use *4* digits in a group instead of the expected, 3? You are asking for a very specific custom format. In this case you can create your own custom formatter. That's described in [How to: Define and Use Custom Numeric Format Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-define-and-use-custom-numeric-format-providers)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if there are n number of leading zeros we don't have to add comma, i am not asking specifically 4

Comment: @VMan the point is that you're asking for a very specific custom format. The way to do that is through a custom format provider

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is it possible without custom format? don't we have a predefined way

Comment: @Vman No, it is not possible. And you should discuss the issue with whoever made that request. It makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Vman you're asking for some predefined way for a very unusual, very specific *custom* format. The format pattern syntax can't cover *everything*. That's why custom formatters exist, to easily implement such custom formats in a reusable way